# Bitcoin data (minutes time frame)?

Tags: time-series, historical-data, bitcoin

Where can I find a correct data of BTC/USD with a minute time frame?
I've downloaded a minutes data from [this site](https://www.cryptodatadownload.com/data/binance/)

I've compared (with the original one from the exchange Binance) the last day (from 2021-18-08 01:40 to 2021-19-08 01:40) with a minutes timeframe.

You can clearly see from the images below, that the downloaded data are completely different from the original one of Binance.

If I need to make an analysis of the price of Bitcoin intraday I can't because these data are very wrong[image: Original Graph from Binance]

[image: Data downloaded from the site]

You can notice from the graphs that before, in the previous 2-3hrs, the double top of yesterday happened (that reached 46k) the price range was around 45.3k.. BUT in the downloaded graph this part is completely missing, (according the wrong data the price before the double top is below 45k). These data are wrong.

Where can I find data that are correct for the pair BTC/USD? Thank You

Comment: The top graph shows BTC/BUSD, where BUSD is the binance usd stable coin. Try and compare your downloaded data to the currency pair [BTC/USD](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?symbol=BITSTAMP%3ABTCUSD) and see if the comparison is better.

Comment: Since Binance doesn't have direct USD pair, I've downloaded the BTC/USDT (from the site), If I check the data of BTC/USDT in Binance (so the original data) they are completely equal to BTC/BUSD. So I think the error still remains the data are not correct. From the site I'm downloading Binance data...

Comment: Okay, I understand. IMHO, it's never a good idea to do a visual comparison, since the scales of the axes can be completely different between the plots, which might misguide you (especially when you don't have timestamps on your second plot). Also, if you have OHLC data, you can try and do a bar-plot instead of a line-plot for better comparison. Alternatively, you can download cryptocurrency data from sites like [Alphavantage.co](https://www.alphavantage.co/) or [Polygon](https://polygon.io/) if you feel like the data is wrong or want to try something else :-)